# Need help Checklist to determine if SP servers are operating as expected after a Microsoft monthly patch deployment

Tags: 2013, 2007, patching

After a patch is deployed to my SP2007 farm, I go through a checklist to make sure the servers in my farm are operating as expected.

**SP 2007 environment:**

- 2 WFE
- 1 INDEX SERVER
- 1 DB
- 1 LOAD BALANCER

**SP 2013 Environment**

- 2 WFE
- 2 APP
- 2 DB
- 1 LOAD BALANCER

Below is a checklist I go through after a patch(Microsoft monthly patches) is deployed throughout the SP 2007 farm 
SharePoint 2007
**WFE & Index**

- Check if these services are running: IISAdmin, W3SVC, SPTimerV3, SP
  Admin

**Index**

- Check if this service is running: SPSearch

**WFE**
Verify that the appropriate application pools are started (ex sharepoint-80, central admin, etc.)
Servers on the NLB are acting as a load balanced server. (Servers' statuses must be converged)

Can I use this same checklist for my 2013 environment? Should I be checking for anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what we have in farm, after installation and config wizard completed.

1) Verify that Build number( should be new).
2) from manage server in Farm > make sure no server required update
3) From Central admin > upgrade migration > review database status and make sure all DB should "no Action required"
4) make sure, all app pools are running on all servers
5) timer services and Admin services running on all server
6) From Central Admin > manager services on server, all required services started on appropriate servers.
7)For search, run the crawl and make sure its completed without issue
8)for UPA, run the UPA Sync and make sure completed without issue.
9) browse all web Apps and make sure up and running.
10)Make sure all your customization working as expected, if there is any modification in web.config or 15 hive...make sure exist their,
10)last thing, you should have a end user testing, which you execute after every updates.  End User testing mean, in a test site collections, create subsite, create workflow, execute a workflow, upload files, delete the files, etc
and also test the functionality which introduces or test the fixes.

In SP2013, there is workflow manager, make sure your workflow working as expected and if you have OWA then test that as well.
Hopefully this help you.